# Produce every combination of two numbers up to eg 1000

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to compare every possible combination of numbers up to 1000 (or higher).

Eg
1 and 1
1 and 2
1 and 3....
2 and 1
2 and 2
2 and 3... 
3 and 1

How can I do this in Objective-C (Specifically iOS programming)?

Im not too fussed if 1 and 2 and 2 and 1 happen, however it would be preferable not to happen.

Im guessing some 'for' loops and a lot of integer work is required.

Does anyone have a code snippet to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like homework... but why iOS? General programming is usually learnt on a more traditional platform.

Comment: No, I was just tinkering after a long spell away from programming.

Comment: Just so everyone knows. The point of this was to find if ((a*b) == (a+b)) was true for anything else but 2 and 2. It isn't for any real whole numbers up to 1000 at this stage.

Comment: that might be a question worthy of http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i >=1000; i++){
   for (int q=1; q >=1000; q++){
     if (i > q){
     }
   }
}
```

hope so

Comment: I had to change it to <= 1000 but other than that this worked. Didn't know/hadn't seen a for inside a for before. Very cool.